# creat react app dangerouslySetInnerHTML image path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using create react app to a small project where i had to injected a html. I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML and it works. The problem is that inside that html i have some img tag with relative external path in the src. 
like that:

`<img src="/var/exmple-fake-image/images//f0026-012.jpg" width="1312" height="1629" style="border: 0px  ;" alt="f0026-01" title="f0026-01">`

when i run the app locally it completes the src with http://localhost:3000/var/exmple-fake-image/images//f0026-012.jpg

How can i change this to complete it with the correct path ? i still want to run it locally

All the images in the inject html need to be completed with the same path (https://cdn2.audiencemedia.com) so i need a way to add this path instead of the http://localhost:3000/ that is added.

correct path for the fake example
https://cdn2.audiencemedia.com/var/exmple-fake-image/images//f0026-012.jpg

I hope i've explained myself well

SOLUTION: i just added `"proxy": "https://cdn2.audiencemedia.com",` in package.json. Was easier than i thought.

Comment: Welcome Bryan! What is the correct path that you want the link to point to?

Comment: Well in that case all the img tag need to add that path https://cdn2.audiencemedia.com/ so taking my previous fake example the correct path should be https://cdn2.audiencemedia.com/var/exmple-fake-image/images//f0026-012.jpg instead of http://localhost:3000/var/exmple-fake-image/images//f0026-012.jpg . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `src` attribute doesn't have a hostname, only a path starting with `/`, it's resolved relative to the current domain.

You could fix this in one of two ways:

The easiest is to simply add the full domain to the src attribute, so instead have `src="https://cdn2.audiencemedia.com/var/exmple-fake-image/images//f0026-012.jpg"`.

A more complicated solution that would allow you to avoid hardlinking to that domain in your code is to proxy image requests through your development server to `cdn2.audiencemedia.com`. How to do this depends on what server you're using to serve the static react files.